# Iterating through a Map in Apex and output another Map

Tags: apex

I have a map in the form :   0:"string1", 1:"string2", 2:"string3" and I would like to call an apex class loop on this map and my output will be: "string1": Count1, "string2": Count2, "string3": Count3 where count1/2/3 are integer counts

my counts should be derived from such code:

```
return [SELECT count (Name)
                FROM Lead 
                WHERE Market__c = :MarketId 
                AND Status = :String1/2/3 ];
```

How can I format my Apex class to get that output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use the [GROUP BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm) SOQL operator.

```
return [SELECT count(Name) recordCount, Status status
        FROM Lead 
        WHERE Market__c = :MarketId 
        AND Status = :sourceMap.values() 
        GROUP BY Status];
```

The [GROUP BY](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm) operator makes it so that the values are grouped by the specified field. `sourceMap.values()` is used as you stated the input values are a map.

If it's just a List, you can:

```
return [SELECT count(Name) recordCount, Status status
        FROM Lead 
        WHERE Market__c = :MarketId 
        AND Status = :statusValues 
        GROUP BY Status];
```

Note that the return type will be an [AggregateResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query_aggregateresult.htm). You can also read more about [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).